# how to use gcc like assembler?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, assembly

is it possible? I want to use `gcc` like `assembler` and after compile it to executable on ubuntu.

I tried it:

```
gcc a.asm -o out.o
```

and from `out.o` file compiler it to `.out` executable file.

but I get the following error:

```
file format not recognized; treating as linker script.
```

I'm new on linux environment. I hope this is clean for you. Any help is very appreciadted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change file name a.asm to a.s and let gcc autodetect assembler (by extension).

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation for the `-x` option to `gcc`. It allows you to specify the language of the source file.